# How to use awk to find the line starting with a variable

Tags: awk

I know 2 things about awk:

1.

```
PAT='aGeneName'
awk -v var="$PAT" '$3 ~ var {print $0}' file.txt  # will print the line where 3rd field includes the variable $PAT
```

2.

`awk '$3 ~ /^aGeneName/' file.txt  # will print the line where 3rd field starts with string "aGeneName"`

But what I want is the combination of these two: I want to print the line where the 3rd field starts with the variable $PAT, something like

```
PAT='aGeneName'
awk -v var="$PAT" '$3 ~ /^var/ {print $0}' file.txt  # but this is wrong, since variable can't be put into //
```

Comment: why not just `PAT='^pattern'`?

Comment: Thank you, that works in my simple example. But that will change the variable, so in a more complex situation where the variable needs to be reused as its original form ("pattern" in this case) this will bring problems

Comment: Don't use the word `pattern` for comparisons in software as it's highly ambiguous. Always use the words `string` or `regexp` instead (or `globbing pattern` if you're matching file names in shell) so it's clear to you and anyone reading your code or requirements what kind of matching you want.

Comment: Thank you Ed Morton. You're right. I've changed the "pattern" to "aGeneName", both in the question and the selected answer. But after I edited the answer from Tiw, it said that "This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed." Hope it will soon be peer reviewed and all readers can see the revised version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is like this:

```
PAT='aGeneName'
awk -v var="$PAT" '$3 ~ "^" var {print $0}' file.txt
```

And the `{print $0}` can be saved here, it's implied.

Another way, when the pattern `var` is a simple string, no *RegEX* character inside:

```
PAT='aGeneName'
awk -v var="$PAT" 'index($3, var)==1' file.txt
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Both of them works perfectly for me.

Comment: @XiaokangZH I accepted your edit, and improved it a little bit, as I think if we use `aGeneName` in the description too, it will leads another kind of ambiguous :)